# Is it possible to query AWS Redshift with PHP's PDO Postgres driver?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I can't find any information relating to this on Amazon's site, but is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure you can,

I am using PHP PostgreSQL to query AWS Redshift

Comment: Congratulations on your first accepted answer! The irony is that our system admin installed the PDO-Postgres and Postgres packages on our server a month ago and I've been writing scripts that `UNLOAD` data from Redshift into S3 since then. I completely forgot I posted this question when I was trying to get PDO-Postgres working on my Mac OS X (it didn't).

Comment: Did you unload because you had problems or because you needed PHP PDO Postgres drivers? If I understood it's because PDO Postgres related, right?
 I have a "high volume" logging server that I'm thinking on moving from MySQL to Redshift.  Any comments?

Answer (score 9):

For those who are looking for examples:

```
$connection = new PDO(
    'pgsql:dbname=<db_name>;host=<redshift_cluster_host>;port=5439',
    '<master_user_name>', 
    '<master_user_password>'
);

$statement = $connection->prepare('<your_query>');
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetch();
```

Also, ensure you configured your cluster security groups correctly (under Security tab in the AWS Redshift admin).